# Flickering when updating the datacontext in background

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp

I'm studying UWP by Windows 10 development for absolute beginners, and I meet some problems.
Reflash my ObservableCollection<> data will cause the screen to flash. How do I fix it?
The program details are in [UWP beginner](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-044-Adeptly-Adaptive-Challenge)

```
    //CS FILE CODE

    public sealed partial class FinancialPage : Page
    {
        ObservableCollection<NewsItem> NewsItems;
        public FinancialPage()
        {
            NewsItems = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>();
            this.InitializeComponent();
            GetNewsItemManager.GetNewItemsByCategory(NewsItems, "Financial");
        } 
    }

    // XAML FILE CODE
    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind NewsItems}" Background="LightGray">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:NewsItem">
                <local:NewsContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>

    //MODELS NEWSITEMS CLASS FILE
    public static void GetNewItemsByCategory(ObservableCollection<NewsItem> NewsItems, string Category)
    {
        var allnewsitems = getNewsItems();
        var filteredNewsItems = allnewsitems.Where(p => p.Category == Category && IsExist(NewsItems, p.Id)).ToList();    
        filteredNewsItems.ForEach(p => NewsItems.Add(p));
    }

    private static Boolean IsExist(ObservableCollection<NewsItem> NewsItems, int Id)
    {
        return NewsItems.ToList().TrueForAll(p => Id == p.Id);
    }

    private static List<NewsItem> getNewsItems()
    {
        var items = new List<NewsItem>();

        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 1, Category = "Financial", Headline = "Lorem Ipsum", Subhead = "doro sit amet", DateLine = "Nunc tristique nec", Image = "Assets/Financial1.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 2, Category = "Financial", Headline = "Etiam ac felis viverra", Subhead = "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", DateLine = "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue", Image = "Assets/Financial2.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 3, Category = "Financial", Headline = "Integer sed turpis erat", Subhead = "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", DateLine = "in viverra metus facilisis sed", Image = "Assets/Financial3.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 4, Category = "Financial", Headline = "Proin sem neque", Subhead = "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", DateLine = "Integer eleifend", Image = "Assets/Financial4.png" }); items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 5, Category = "Financial", Headline = "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", Subhead = "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", DateLine = "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", Image = "Assets/Financial5.png" });

        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 6, Category = "Food", Headline = "Lorem ipsum", Subhead = "dolor sit amet", DateLine = "Nunc tristique nec", Image = "Assets/Food1.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 7, Category = "Food", Headline = "Etiam ac felis viverra", Subhead = "vulputate nisl ac, aliquet nisi", DateLine = "tortor porttitor, eu fermentum ante congue", Image = "Assets/Food2.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 8, Category = "Food", Headline = "Integer sed turpis erat", Subhead = "Sed quis hendrerit lorem, quis interdum dolor", DateLine = "in viverra metus facilisis sed", Image = "Assets/Food3.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 9, Category = "Food", Headline = "Proin sem neque", Subhead = "aliquet quis ipsum tincidunt", DateLine = "Integer eleifend", Image = "Assets/Food4.png" });
        items.Add(new NewsItem() { Id = 10, Category = "Food", Headline = "Mauris bibendum non leo vitae tempor", Subhead = "In nisl tortor, eleifend sed ipsum eget", DateLine = "Curabitur dictum augue vitae elementum ultrices", Image = "Assets/Food5.png" });
        return items;
        }
```

Comment: If you are driving the contents of the collection by the selected type (financial or food), you are likely populating the list in the constructor, then it is immediately repopulating with the same list when the UI loads and the selected item triggers the population.  If that is the case, simply do not load the list in the constructor of the page and let the page markup do its job.

Comment: How to do that? I put my code in there. @MarkW  [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkRw7qjRNGihJUkpeF5uv3m3tgrvg)

Comment: Just looking at your code, you are navigating to the Financial page twice - once in the constructor, then again when the UI updates the selected item in the listbox.  Try commenting out the navigation in the constructor.  Alternatively, before navigating, check the current frame content and don't navigate if it is the same type of page.

Comment: that is not the issue... will post answer shortly.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Dounx... no real answer.  It is definitely updating the datacontext of the usercontrol, which is what causes the flicker.  You can make it stop by using Binding rather than Bind, but it is still updating the datacontext in the background twice for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
NewsItem.Clear();
filteredNewsItems.ForEach(p => NewsItem.Add(p));
```

should be

```
NewsItems.Clear();
filteredNewsItems.ForEach(p => NewsItems.Add(p));
```

I assume the "flash" you are seeing (can't be certain as you haven't provided a full repro) is due to what you're doing to show the updated list.

Yes, removing everything and then adding a new (mostly similar) list back can create what some people describe as a "flash".

A better approach would be to remove the items you don't want displayed any more and then add in any extra ones you do.
Something like this:

```
        foreach (var newsItem in NewsItems.Reverse())
        {
            if (newsItem.Category != Category)
            {
                NewsItems.Remove(newsItem);
            }
        }
        foreach (var fni in filteredNewsItems)
        {
            if (!NewsItems.Contains(fni))
            {
                NewsItems.Add(fni);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I delete the clear() and follow your suggestion, add a IsExist() fuction. But I find it still flash, although I have the same data (It will not be added into the ObservableCollection), Why?

Comment: @Dounx I had the exact issue few weeks ago with one of my App and Matt Lacey's Second Approach _remove the items you don't want displayed any more and then add in any extra ones you do_ was what I used to eliminate the flickering.

Comment: @Dounx I'm still not 100% on what you mean by the "flash" you're reporting. Can you include a way to recreate as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AVKNaidu Well, I can't find that answer. And I needn't remove any items or add, but it still fiicks(After the page loading).

Comment: @MattLacey I put my code in OneDrive [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkRw7qjRNGihJUkpeF5uv3m3tgrvg). After my items loading, the items will flicker again, although the data has not been added.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I've found a solution for you.

Instead of updating the bindings in your user control with the lambda expression, try it this way:

```
public NewsContentControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContextChanged += OnDataCtxChanged; //+= (s, e) => Bindings.Update();
}

private void OnDataCtxChanged(FrameworkElement sender, DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("context 'changed'");
    if(NewsItem != args.NewValue as NewsItem)
    {
        Bindings.Update();
    }
}
```

This triggers the update only if the value is actually different.  Additionally, you can use "Binding" instead of x:Bind.

None of this answers for me why the datacontext is changing... but this should get rid of your flicker.

Comment: note: it is not the lambda usage that is an issue, I just prefer to put it in a method when it is more than one line of code.  You could very well add that code to the lambda if that is what you prefer.

Comment: If you find the reason why the datacontext is changing, please tell me. Anyway, Thanks a lot !